# Cannot add Button below GridView

Tags: android, button, gridview, layout

I want to add a button to my gridview but it doesn't work. I tried with `android:layout_weight="1"` but the button is shown always, and I want to only show the button when the gridview is without any items to show. Thank you.

My source:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
         android:numColumns="auto_fit"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:columnWidth="100dp"
         android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:id="@+id/grid" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comprar"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_red_small"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your understanding of the "layout_weight" parameter is wrong. If one item has a weight and everything else is wrap content, the size of the weighted item fills all the space that remains AFTER the items with wrap content take their required space. If you want to remove the button if the grid is full, use JozeRi's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always go with this approach..
load your data, and then check

```
if (data.size == 0)
```

if it's 0 then your gridview is empty..
use showButton, if not, showGridView..

```
private void showGridView() {
  grid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void showButton() {
  grid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```